# Symfony. Using transactions with 2+ repositories

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In a certain controller I need to do several inserts/updates in the database. I'm using 4 repositories of 4 entities for that, but I need this to be done in a unit of work.

I know that I can do these inserts/updates directly on the controller and use `$em->getConnection()->beginTransaction()`, `$em->getConnection()->rollBack()` and `$em->getConnection()->commit()` to ensure that all or none are done. But this goes against symfony best practices, so I'd like to use repositories.

I've seen [this tutorial](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/cookbook/creating-a-unit-of-work-using-doctrine.html) for Doctrine 1, but it seems like a very complex solution to something that is supposed to be simpler.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

edit, I'm using Symfony 3.3.5.

edit2, I add an example of what I want to do. The whole process is to add a message written by a worker to the rest of his department mates, all within a company. The message may or may not have attachments (let's say it does). These files should appear as department and company files, so that even if the department is deleted, the files continue to appear as belonging to the company.

I haven't included error handling in the code to make it simpler.

```
// New Files
$file1 = new File(); // AppBundle\Entity\File
$file1->setName("name1");
$file2 = new File();
$file2->setName("name2");

$em->getRepository('AppBundle:File')->insert($file1);
$em->getRepository('AppBundle:File')->insert($file2);

// New Post
$post = new Post(); // AppBundle\Entity\Post
$post->setContent($some_text)
  ->setAuthor($some_user) // AppBundle\Entity\User
  ->addFile($file1)
  ->addFile($file2);

$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->insert($post);

// Getting company and department
$company    = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Company')->findOneByCode($some_company_code);
$department = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Department')->findOneByCode($some_dept_code);

$company->addFile($file1)->addFile($file2);
$department->addFile($file1)->addFile($file2);

$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Company')->update($company);
$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Department')->update($department);

// Notifications
$notif = new Notification(); // AppBundle\Entity\Notification
$notif->setText("Text")
  ->setPost($post)
  ->addAddressee($some_dept_member)
  ->addAddressee($other_dept_member);

$notif = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Notification')->insert($notif);
```

Comment: First of all, you've asked a very broad question. Hard to help without any code. Next thing is that repositories are not supposed to modify data, but only to fetch it, so repositories are not the place to that such work.

Comment: Doesn't doctrine automatically wrap all scheduled operations inside a single transaction when `flush()` is called? MAybe this could help: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html

Comment: @Jakub, I didn't write any code because I think anyone who has used symfony can get an idea of what I am asking. Also, I guess it's something that most people have faced, so it's a bit surprising for me that I haven't found any answers here. The documentation says about the repositories "Doctrine provides special repository classes that allow you to keep all your query logic in one, central place". That's why I wanted to do it that way. Joe, I know how to use transactions, but the documentation doesn't explain what I'm asking (or I didn't find that)

Comment: Yes, but in this context query, means to fetch data. Insert/update/delete are commands (CQS pattern). Also I have an idea of what you're trying to do, but the solution could depend on what exact operations you want to do. Maybe you need a service for this. Maybe all operations should be encapsulated inside an aggregate entity. Well, it always depends.

Comment: Wow! I misunderstood it (English is not my first language). If the repositories are only used to fetch data and everything else can be done on a controller, everything is much easier for me now. Anyway, I edited my post summarizing what I was trying to do, but if I put inserts and updates in the controller and not in repositories, my original problem disappears

Answer (score 0):

In repositories you should only fetch entities or execute queries with DQL that retrieve some data.

Every time you need to create a new row in your db, you have to inform the entity manager that you want to persist the entity, calling `$em->persist($myNewEntity)`. This inform the entity manager that that entity should be persisted to dB.

Once you have created (and persisted) all your entities and/or modified your fetched entities, you can call `$em->persist()` just once: the entity manager will do all the needed insert/update/delete in a single transaction to your dB.

If you also need to retrieve/fetch data in the same transaction you should consider including all your code in a callback function and pass it to the entity manager, like this

```
$myCallback=function($em) {
    //Do all here: access repositories, create new entities, edit entities
    //...
    //no need to call $em->flush(), it will be called by Doctrine after the execution of the callback
};
$em->transactional($myCallback) ;
```